# I sent an unupdated version of my MSc. thesis to a supervisor of a PhD project I am applying for

Tags: phd, thesis, masters

I am being considered for a doctoral position and after what I think it was a very good interview, the project supervisor asked me for a copy of my MSc. thesis. Even though the results of the thesis have not been published yet, he assured me full confidentiality, so I sent the thesis for his appreciation.

Two days after sending the document, I have realized I have sent the wrong version of it. These version was very close to the final one, but with a few minor mistakes, such as grammar and a few misplaced commas, one legend that was partially wrong, and differences in text colour also in one legend.

I really want the position, and I am very afraid these minor mistakes will make me come across as sloppy.

Do you think I should send an email explaining the situation and, likewise, send the "good version" of my thesis? I am also very afraid that this will make me come across as sloppy. After all, I did not make 100% sure I was sending the proper updated version.

What would you do in my situation?

I really appreciate all the help!!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Even final published theses can, and do, have errors.

Don’t worry, if the errors are typos etc you will be fine, however if there is a serious error in the theory or analysis then that may be different.

Comment: Hi @Solar! Thank you for your feedback! I think the biggest error is that I named wrongly the y-axis labels in two graphs. So, in the text and in the legend of the figure it says, ie.: "data A" is shown, but then the y-axis label says i.e.: "data B". Nonetheless, the figure shown is still related to "data A" and only the y-axis label is wrong. Should I be worried about this then? Apart from this, the errors are only typos. Thanks again!!

Comment: Also @Solar , most of the typos are in the results section, which I believe that, together with the discussion, is to where people look most at. Should I be worried about it as well? Thank you so much again for the feedback!!

Comment: These sound like typos, which, as SolarMike correctly says, are unlikely to be a problem. Professors are busy, it's hard to imagine they will read the entire document in detail, let alone be concerned about some typos. At the same time, it's probably also find to send a **brief** (i.e., one-sentence) e-mail with the updated draft.

Answer (score -1):

I think most people have done this at some point, it is unfortunate that it happened when applying for that position. I would send him the updated version with a small explanation stating that it corrects some small grammar/color/graph/ect issues. If he hasn't already read the paper, I'm sure he would like an updated one.